# How to apply permanently setxkbmap setting for all users on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Tags: keyboard, locale, settings

I've found the command to set my keyboard output to Belgian, but everytime I restart my computer I can't use some typical characters.

Example: "T^ete" instead of "Tête" *(What means "head" in French for who doesn't know)*

I can change it, but I can't save it. And it should apply to all the users on my computer.

I do not like to edit configuration files because I'm not comfortable in the syntax I should use.
Is there a terminal command to apply this or a GUI setting ?

Comment: I think I found the solution on https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/tutoriel/configurer_le_clavier
For the restart it's ok.
I still have to test the other users, and after an update what the results will be.

Comment: I assume you use a command, like `setxkbmap fr` to "change it", am I right? If so, you can try to put the command in a file like `~/.xsessionrc` (name may change depending on your distro).

Comment: If you have found a solution from the link above, would you summarize it in an Answer below? Thank you!